# How to display things in html with Java Beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, javabeans

I am newbie with Spring, Themeleaf and Beans. I created my on Java Bean and I want to display staff mainly text in html.

This is my Bean

```
package com.example.platformylab03;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Book {
    private String author;
    private String title;

    public Book() {
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Obvious SpringBootApp:

```
package com.example.platformylab03;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PlatformyLab03Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PlatformyLab03Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p th:text="${Book.author}" />
</body>
</html>
```

If possible please explain it on code sample or link me useful page.
Thanks <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create a controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  @GetMapping("/page")
  public String main(Map<String, Object> model) {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setAuthor("Alastair Reynolds");
    book.setTitle("Revelation Space");
    
    model.put("book", book);
    return "page";
  }
}
```

Then make sure you're template is named "page.html" (same as the return string on your controller).  I put mine in `Other Sources/templates/page.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p th:text="${book.author}" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Once everything is linked together, access `/page/` on your server.

Comment: Just an additional note: `Book` should not be a `@Component`